# Removing ajax loaded page and retain original div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following functionn called when a link is clicked. The function loads a new page over a div through ajax.

```
<pre><code>
    function getSummary(id)
{
    loadPage_signup = "new_user.php";
    loadPage_benef = "readercycle_benef.php";
    $.ajax({
      url:"new_user.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      success:function() {
         $("#readercycle_benef_container").load(loadPage_benef);       
         $("#rc_main_header_login").load(loadPage_signup);
      }
    });
}
</code></pre>
```

In this newly loaded page through ajax, a cancel button exists. On clicking this cancel button, the ajax loaded page should be removed and must retain the original div content.

I wrote the below function that is intended do this functionality. But this is not working. The ajax loaded page is removed, but the original div does not come up with children.
Please help me understand what went wrong!

```
<pre><code>
function closeDiv(id) {
    $(id).remove();
    $ret = $("#rc_main_header_login").show();
    $("#rc_main_header_login").nextAll().show();
}


<input type="button" id="button_cancel" name="btnCancel" value="cancel" onClick="closeDiv('#rc_main_header_newuser')" />
</pre></code>
```

Comment: You need to save the `.html()` of the div to a variable before you load the new content, so that you can switch back to it later.

Comment: Are you storing the original div somewhere?  If you are just overwriting the contents, then the original div is lost.  You should store the div somewhere and then reattach it if you cancel.

Comment: @scrowler How do I save the content? Please help me with this.

Comment: @zero298 How do I save the content? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the original contents into global variables so you can restore it later.

**jQuery:**

```
var original_content_benef = '';
var original_content_rc = '';

function getSummary(id)
{
    loadPage_signup = "new_user.php";
    loadPage_benef = "readercycle_benef.php";
    $.ajax({
        url:"new_user.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function() {
            // save original content
            original_content_benef = $("#readercycle_benef_container").html();
            original_content_rc = $("#rc_main_header_login").html();
            // replace content
            $("#readercycle_benef_container").load(loadPage_benef);       
            $("#rc_main_header_login").load(loadPage_signup);
        }
    });
}

function closeDiv(id) {
    $(id).remove();
    // restore original content
    $("#readercycle_benef_container").html(original_content_benef);
    $("#rc_main_header_login").html(original_content_rc);
    // do your showing
    $ret = $("#rc_main_header_login").show();
    $("#rc_main_header_login").nextAll().show();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="button_cancel" name="btnCancel" value="cancel" onClick="closeDiv('#rc_main_header_newuser')" />
```